# Repair all "broken" Metro apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, repair, windows-store-app

It often happens to me that a lot of Windows 8 Metro apps need to be repaired (i.e. cannot be opened). Is there a way to repair them all at once?

Answer (score 1):

If they don't work, test the [app troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185).

Is the tool able to fix the issues?

Comment: I can't reach the website at the moment... Will check later.

Comment: and have you checked it? Was the troubleshooter helpful?

Comment: Is this still an issue in 8.0 RTM? After several breakages in 8.0 preview, I accepted it as severe beta software instability and ditched it as Window 7 is a mature and stable platform.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs yes, I still see users having issues to run the new apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the patch:

The only thing you need to do is to go to Control Panel, and in the search bar, type "guest" then you got "create guest session". Click on it, validate
then go the Start screen and click on your avatar in upper right, and click "Guest"

It will load it, it take one or two minutes, then return to your session by the Start screen and all metro apps will work again.

I think this reactivate some DLLs or components, but it works 100%.